# How many uilocalnotifications can set at a time?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am setting around 370 `UILocalNotification`s but I can only set 64...

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i<[arr count] ; i++){

        UILocalNotification* alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];


        // Create a new notification.
        if (alarm)
        {
            alarm.fireDate = indDate;
            alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            //alarm.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
            alarm.soundName = @"alarmsound.caf";
            alarm.alertBody = @"Message";
            [app scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];

        }
}
```

Comment: The maximum number of UILocalNotification in IOS is 64.

Comment: its iOS default you can only set **64** local notification per app. you can do one thing that when you app launch check  `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications];` it will give you total remaining notifications. if its is <64 then set new notifications.

Comment: If you want to add more than 64 notification you have to delete the old notifications or firing the scheduled notifications

Comment: @rjv kumar hi ,One another way to register more.Store in the local database and register  fist 64 and when `notification` fire then again register one bye one . Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to all...i ll reschedule the remaining...

Comment: If i change the time i.e after the current date, then i am receiving previous notifications..but i don't want those..help me guys...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maximum limit is 64.
I have also the same problem where i need to schedule many notifications.
I have scheduled 64 notifications and when the app again opens I will schedule the remaining notifications.

[For more Info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in iOS 8.1 it is possible to schedule more than 64 notifications and all get fired. In my app I tested it with 500 and more local notifications and all get scheduled and fired on iPhone Simulator an on a real iPhone 5s.
Maybe this is a bug in iOS 8.1 or Apple forgot to update the documentation.

Comment: In iOS 10 you can't schedule more then 64 notifications even with the new UserNotifications framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can set at most 64 local notifications to system, one trick is that repeated notification is treated as one notification no matter how many times or how frequently it repeat.